# Java 2D: Render a very large amount of tiles on screen quickly

Tags: java, performance, 2d, render, paintcomponent

Another quick question if anyone is up to it.  I have this code:

```
        for(int cy = 0; cy < 3; cy++) {
            for(int cx = 0; cx < 3; cx++) {
                for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
                    for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
                        g2D.drawImage(Tiles.tileImages.get(C0.chunk[x][y][cx][cy]), 
                                C0.cX[cx][cy] * cspcr + (blckspcr * x) + width - pXspcr,
                                C0.cY[cx][cy] * cspcr + (blckspcr * y) + height - pYspcr + (int)(24.25 * zoom),
                                    blckspcr, blckspcr, null);
                        if(C0.chunk[x][y][cx][cy].equals("a05")) {
                            g2D.drawImage(Tiles.treetop, 
                                    C0.cX[cx][cy] * cspcr + (blckspcr * x) + width - pXspcr,
                                    C0.cY[cx][cy] * cspcr + (blckspcr * y) + height - pYspcr + (int)(24.25 * zoom) - blckspcr,
                                    blckspcr, blckspcr, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but my problem is, it creates an incredibly large amount lag in my application.  Is there any way where I could avoid using the large amounts of loops I have or possibly speed it up?  The image it is drawing first is grabbing blocks from chunks in a 4D array of strings and gets images from a hashmap based on the string and then it draws the image using a bunch of numbers.  If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your data in a different way (a 4D array is almost always a  bad idea).

You can begin replacing those 4D array of strings by maybe a hash if its fits your usecase (then you'd only have one loop).

Comment: How could I implement that? Like how would I store a 4D array in a hash?

Comment: You can tell us why you use 4D arrays. What data does it represent?

Comment: Data values loaded from a file in string form to be accessed in the hashmap to get an image to paint onto the screen.  I use 4D because it is easy to access to allow for chunking of a map

Comment: Instead of using the 4 strings, hash them into one string, and make your hashmap in terms of hashes.

Comment: They are one string already and I access them as one string.  Each number you put into each dimension pops out a string

Comment: I realize that, but, you wouldn't have four loops if you didn't have a 4D array, collapse it into a 1D array!

Comment: Ok I'll try that but I will still be looping the same code 2304 times.  Would it make any difference?

Comment: No, you wouldn't. You only hash the ones that don't repeat. And, drawing any image more than 1000 times is going to kill speed.